# Blocking browser with huge exchange between Web browser and python through websocket

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, raspberry-pi

I use websocket for exchange between Robot on Raspberry Pi under python, and web browser application with html, js and jquery.
Robot gives its angular position coming from magnetometer chip, and webbrowser display robot direction.
WebBrowser receives at least 5 messages by second, and block.
How to gives some "breathes" to the browser to avoid that ?
Best regards

Comment: Are you running web server in Rasperry Pi or in separate computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid blocking behaviour in the browser you need to clear up some space in the event loop. For a good explanation of that, you can check out this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

To explain what happens: Your browser is blocked processing data, and it needs 'breathing space' to repaint visually the changes that have happened. If you break up the data flow and use some setTimeout's you give your browser time in between to 'breathe'. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not fluent english speaking... So, I receive and process the data through the 'onmessage' callback. And I thought it was independant of the browser process. Can you give me some 'written' links or articles with some 'breathing space'. On VB net / C# we have the doevents...

Comment: The browser contains a JavaScript Runtime Environment, part of this is the event loop. If you put some heavy computation in there it doesn't allow the browser to do a 'repaint', which is updating what you see in the browser. Without seeing the code it might be hard to advise exactly what to do, but maybe you can add a timeout in the callback function to give space to 'repaint'.

Comment: Ok, it's perfect. I add 'setTimeout(functionNothing, 20);' which do nothing, and works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: If it's solved the problem please accept the answer as solved so others don't need to read through the comments to see it it worked!